# Choice of approximate posterior in variational inference with positive support

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, graphical-model

I have a simple probabilistic graphical model: $z \longrightarrow x$ where $z_i \sim Exp\left(\lambda_i\right)$ where subscript $i$ denotes the $i$th dimension and $x|z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(f\left(z\right), \sigma^2\right)$ where $f$ is some real valued function (usually non-linear). I'm using variational inference to approximate the posterior $p\left(z|x\right)$. Let's say $q_{\phi}\left(z|x\right)$ is the approximate posterior with $\theta$ being the parameters.

Since $z$ is a positive random variable, I cannot use the prototypical normal distribution assumption for $q$. Furthermore I also want the posterior to have some correlation structure like in a multivariate normal distribution.

My idea is to indeed use a multivariate normal distribution but only as the base distribution and add a positive, bijective transformation, $T$ on top such that my target distribution has positive support, retains a correlation structure and the bijective transformation renders a full likelihood computation. Basically: $q_{\phi}\left(z|x\right) \equiv \mathcal{N}\left(z|x\right)\left|\operatorname{det} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \mathbf{z}}\right|^{-1}$.

What are some good choices for $T$? And what are some other distributions I can use in general in that allow dependencies between dimensions, and have positive support?

So far I have tried the exponential function as a transformation on top of multivariate normal, which is essentially a multivariate lognormal.

Comment: The Softplus can be pretty nice as a bijection since it is linear as $x\to\infty$ instead of exploding like the exp function does. See e.g. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softplus.html